# Ant script is not getting completed for starting tomcat server in local mac machine

Tags: jenkins, tomcat, ant

I used bellow ANT script to start Tomcat in local mac machine with Jenkins.

```
<java classname="org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap" fork="true" spawn="false">
   <classpath path="${server.location}/bin/bootstrap.jar:${server.location}/bin/tomcat-juli.jar" />
   <jvmarg value="-Dcatalina.home=${server.location}" />
   <arg line="start" />
</java>
```

```
<exec executable="/bin/sh" os="Mac OS X" dir="${server.location}/bin" failonerror="true">
         <arg value="-c"/>
         <arg value="./catalina.sh run"/>
        </exec>
```

The corresponding targets getting executed. But it is not stoping.

TomCat Version : 9.0.33

Attaching the Jenkins log [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMHNJ.png)

I used `<forget>` Ant-Contrib tag also. But no use.

Comment: Ant will wait for the called program to terminate unless you specify spawn="true" in the exec task.  Adding that should fix your issue.

Comment: Sorry, I tried the same with spawn="true". But not use.. The Server get stopped with the Jenkins job get completed.